# Notepad++ Regex: Match all occurrences after another match

Tags: notepad++, regex

How to match all occurrences after another match?

For example: I want to replace all `-` after `abc` with space.

Input:

```
one-two-abc-three-four-five
six-seven-abc-eight-nine-ten
...
```

Output:

```
one-two-abc three four five
six-seven-abc eight nine ten
...
```

In Javascript is possible to use this regex: `(?<=(.+abc.+))-`, but the [`Positive Lookbehind`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) seems not to be supported in Notepad++

Thanks.

PS: Feel free to correct the Title. I did my best, but I'm not native speaker.

Comment: I'm able to find the first occurence after `and` with `^(.*and)(-([^-]+))`, but when I try to make the second "group" `(-([^-]+))` repeated with `*` (=`(-([^-]+))*`) it makes full text match. See: [https://regex101.com/r/oAeXIj/1](https://regex101.com/r/oAeXIj/1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work with any number of hyphens in the string.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^.*abc|\G[^-\r\n]+)\K-`
- Replace with:   # a single space
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
  ^             # beginning of line
    .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
    abc         # literally abc
  |           # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
    [^-\r\n]+   # 1 or more any character that is not hyphen or line break
)               # end group
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
-               # hyphen
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about [`\G`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) and [`\K`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) "operators". I made them clickable here in comment for others who want to know more about them.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution.

```
Find:
^(.+abc)(-([^-]*))?(-([^-]*))?(-([^-]*))?(-([^-]*))?(-([^-]*))?(-([^-]*))?$

Replace:
$1 $3 $5 $7 $11 $13
```

**These caveats you need to be aware of:**

1. All wanted (replaced) occurrences of `-` are after the last occurrence of `abc`.
2. `(-([^-]*))?` part of regex is repeated equally or more than max. count of `-`  in a single line.
3. There will be extra spaces on end of each line which has less `-` occurrences than `(-([^-]*))?` count in the regex
4. Number after `$` in replace expression is start by 1 and is +2 for each `(-([^-]*))?` occurrence.

Try this regex online at https://regex101.com/r/BRJjEx/1